# Converting MATLAB 'double' to Python is only supported for 1-dimensional vectors

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

The source code is below:

```
import py.sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression
import py.numpy.asarray


X = randn(100, 2); 
Y = randi([0, 1], 100, 1);  

LR = py.sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(pyargs('class_weight', 'balanced', 'random_state', int64(0)));

model = LR.fit(X, Y);
```

The error:

```
Error using py.sklearn.linear_model._logistic.LogisticRegression/fit
Converting MATLAB 'double' to Python is only supported for 1-dimensional vectors.

Error Untitled4 (line 15)
model = LR.fit(X, Y);
```

How to call the fit function of the LR model in matlab?